# Mongo DB Document limit

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where there is a single document. Inside this document, I have several arrays and other arrays nested. I read somewhere that the maximum size of the document cannot exceed 16MB in the collection. Did I design my collection wrong? Is there any solution? Now that our product is almost getting released, I am not sure how to go about it

```
core collection:
{
 schools:[{
   _id:ObjectId(),
    name:"abc",
    abc1Arr[{},{},{}]
 }],
 xyz:[{},{},{}],

}
```

above one document size cannot be more then 16MB. is it right?

Comment: That is correct. However, to help you, please use proper names. `abc` and `xyz` do not help with that.

Comment: Having only a single huge document in the collection almost certainly is a mistake. Why do you need a collection at all then? You probably want these `schools` and `xyz` to go into their own collections (need more context to say for sure).

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed the max document size is 16mb.

its hard to say wether this design pattern is good (probably not) or bad for your
product as i dont know how your queries look, what you store in the arrays and nested array and so on.

however by assuming an array contains similar "objects" a better design pattern would be having your single document contain array of id's
and those ids would be linked to a documents in a new collection you would open.
making this transfer should not be too hard to execute swiftly.

if you would add more information on how your data is built within the arrays and for what purpose i could offer deeper insight.

Answer (score 0):

Yes maximum of BSON is size 16MB, you can use GridFS API to store large data.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

Answer (score 0):

Don't grow your data set by increasing the size of your documents. Grow your data set by adding new documents. Turn the arrays into collections.

The array of schools should be its own collection. the `xyz` doc should be in its own collection and have a reference back to each element of the `schools` collection.

This is just a guess the actual layout will be determined by your rate of insertion (adding documents with insert is always faster than updating a massive array) and your query patterns. Your query patterns will determine how you index your data.